# How do I type "%" in CMD using VBS

Tags: windows-8

So I'm programing a "fix" for my friend's PC and I need to use VBS to open the CMD prompt and access his `AppData` folders. But when I send `cd %appdata%` to the command prompt with VBS, it only comes out like this `cd appdata` (without any percentage signs).

This is my script for VBS:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )

Wshshell.run "cmd"
Wshshell.sendkeys " "
Wscript.sleep 200
Wshshell.sendkeys "cd %appdata%"
Wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `WshShell.Run "cd %appdata%"`. You may also get it yourself by `appdata=getvar("APPDATA")`.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, this is probably a job for a batch file and not WSH.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this solution explicitly mentioned elsewhere, but this [SendKeys reference](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) gave a clue. You need to wrap the `%` sign in braces (`{}`). So your `%` signs would be `{%}`.

*ex. Literal percents in Visual Basic Script (VBS)*

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )

Wshshell.run "cmd"
Wshshell.sendkeys " "
Wscript.sleep 200
Wshshell.sendkeys "cd {%}appdata{%}"
Wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Thx so much for this, it helped a lot

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it helped. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the username of your friend's pc, you may do this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )

Wshshell.run "cmd"
Wshshell.sendkeys " "
Wscript.sleep 200
Wshshell.sendkeys "cd "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming""
Wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Replace User here to your friend's computer's real username.
Hope that helps you.
:)